# Modify bitrate in AVAsset for cordova Video Editor

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, bitrate, avasset

I need to reduce the dimension of a video taken with an hybrid app without reduce the resolution therefore I'm trying to modify the [cordova video editor plugin](https://github.com/jbavari/cordova-plugin-video-editor) to reduce the dimension of the video by changing the bitrate. 
I've tried to use [SDAVAssetExportSession](https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession) without any success and getting tons of CVPixel errors.
The plugin code is:

```
- (void) transcodeVideo:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    NSDictionary* options = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    if ([options isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        options = [NSDictionary dictionary];
    }

    NSString *assetPath = [options objectForKey:@"fileUri"];
    NSString *videoFileName = [options objectForKey:@"outputFileName"];

    CDVQualityType qualityType = ([options objectForKey:@"quality"]) ? [[options objectForKey:@"quality"] intValue] : LowQuality;

    NSString *presetName = Nil;

    switch(qualityType) {
        case HighQuality:
            presetName = AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality;
            break;
        case MediumQuality:
        default:
            presetName = AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality;
            break;
        case LowQuality:
            presetName = AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality;
    }

    CDVOutputFileType outputFileType = ([options objectForKey:@"outputFileType"]) ? [[options objectForKey:@"outputFileType"] intValue] : MPEG4;

    BOOL optimizeForNetworkUse = ([options objectForKey:@"optimizeForNetworkUse"]) ? [[options objectForKey:@"optimizeForNetworkUse"] intValue] : NO;

    float videoDuration = [[options objectForKey:@"duration"] floatValue];

    BOOL saveToPhotoAlbum = [options objectForKey:@"saveToLibrary"] ? [[options objectForKey:@"saveToLibrary"] boolValue] : YES;

    NSString *stringOutputFileType = Nil;
    NSString *outputExtension = Nil;

    switch (outputFileType) {
        case QUICK_TIME:
            stringOutputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
            outputExtension = @".mov";
            break;
        case M4A:
            stringOutputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
            outputExtension = @".m4a";
            break;
        case M4V:
            stringOutputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4V;
            outputExtension = @".m4v";
            break;
        case MPEG4:
        default:
            stringOutputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
            outputExtension = @".mp4";
            break;
    }

    // remove file:// from the assetPath if it is there
    assetPath = [[assetPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file://" withString:@""] mutableCopy];

    // check if the video can be saved to photo album before going further
    if (saveToPhotoAlbum && !UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(assetPath))
    {
        NSString *error = @"Video cannot be saved to photo album";
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:error ] callbackId:command.callbackId];
        return;
    }

    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *tempVideoPath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%@", docDir, videoFileName, @".mov"];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:assetPath];
    [videoData writeToFile:tempVideoPath atomically:NO];

    AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempVideoPath] options:nil];
    NSArray *compatiblePresets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:avAsset];

    if ([compatiblePresets containsObject:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality])
    {
        AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]initWithAsset:avAsset presetName: presetName];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *videoPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0], videoFileName, outputExtension];

        exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
        exportSession.outputFileType = stringOutputFileType;
        exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = optimizeForNetworkUse;

        NSLog(@"videopath of your file: %@", videoPath);

        if (videoDuration)
        {
            int32_t preferredTimeScale = 600;
            CMTime startTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, preferredTimeScale);
            CMTime stopTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(videoDuration, preferredTimeScale);
            CMTimeRange exportTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startTime, stopTime);
            exportSession.timeRange = exportTimeRange;
        }

        [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
            switch ([exportSession status]) {
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                    if (saveToPhotoAlbum) {
                        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoPath, self, nil, nil);
                    }
                    NSLog(@"Export Complete %d %@", exportSession.status, exportSession.error);
                    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:videoPath] callbackId:command.callbackId];
                    break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                    NSLog(@"Export failed: %@", [[exportSession error] localizedDescription]);
                    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:[[exportSession error] localizedDescription]] callbackId:command.callbackId];
                    break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                    NSLog(@"Export canceled");
                    break;
                default:
                    NSLog(@"Export default in switch");
                    break;
            }
        }];
    }

}
```

How could I implement AVAssetWriter inside the cordova plugin?

```
NSDictionary *settings = @{AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecH264,
                           AVVideoWidthKey:@(video_width),
                           AVVideoHeightKey:@(video_height),
                           AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey:
                               @{AVVideoAverageBitRateKey:@(desired_bitrate),
                                 AVVideoProfileLevelKey:AVVideoProfileLevelH264Main31, /* Or whatever profile & level you wish to use */
                                 AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey:@(desired_keyframe_interval)}};

AVAssetWriterInput* writer_input = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:settings];
```

I don't really need a flexible solution, hardcoding is fine.
I'm not really an Object-C expert (and I find it a quite obscure language)

Comment: WHy don't you ask the author to make the change? Chances are other people need that flexibility too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue with SDAVAssetExportSession. Next, I'm contacting the author to commit the changes. Here is the code (**MUST** be added the CoreVideo.framework):

```
- (void) transcodeVideo:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    NSDictionary* options = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    if ([options isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        options = [NSDictionary dictionary];
    }

    NSString *assetPath = [options objectForKey:@"fileUri"];
    NSString *videoFileName = [options objectForKey:@"outputFileName"];

    CDVQualityType qualityType = ([options objectForKey:@"quality"]) ? [[options objectForKey:@"quality"] intValue] : LowQuality;

    NSString *presetName = Nil;

    switch(qualityType) {
        case HighQuality:
            presetName = AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality;
            break;
        case MediumQuality:
        default:
            presetName = AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality;
            break;
        case LowQuality:
            presetName = AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality;
    }

    CDVOutputFileType outputFileType = ([options objectForKey:@"outputFileType"]) ? [[options objectForKey:@"outputFileType"] intValue] : MPEG4;

    BOOL optimizeForNetworkUse = ([options objectForKey:@"optimizeForNetworkUse"]) ? [[options objectForKey:@"optimizeForNetworkUse"] intValue] : NO;

    float videoDuration = [[options objectForKey:@"duration"] floatValue];

    BOOL saveToPhotoAlbum = [options objectForKey:@"saveToLibrary"] ? [[options objectForKey:@"saveToLibrary"] boolValue] : YES;

    NSString *stringOutputFileType = Nil;
    NSString *outputExtension = Nil;

    switch (outputFileType) {
        case QUICK_TIME:
            stringOutputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
            outputExtension = @".mov";
            break;
        case M4A:
            stringOutputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
            outputExtension = @".m4a";
            break;
        case M4V:
            stringOutputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4V;
            outputExtension = @".m4v";
            break;
        case MPEG4:
        default:
            stringOutputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
            outputExtension = @".mp4";
            break;
    }

    // remove file:// from the assetPath if it is there
    assetPath = [[assetPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file://" withString:@""] mutableCopy];

    // check if the video can be saved to photo album before going further
    if (saveToPhotoAlbum && !UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(assetPath))
    {
        NSString *error = @"Video cannot be saved to photo album";
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:error ] callbackId:command.callbackId];
        return;
    }

    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *tempVideoPath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%@", docDir, videoFileName, @".mov"];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:assetPath];
    [videoData writeToFile:tempVideoPath atomically:NO];

    AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempVideoPath] options:nil];
    NSArray *compatiblePresets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:avAsset];

    SDAVAssetExportSession *encoder = [SDAVAssetExportSession.alloc initWithAsset:avAsset];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *videoPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0], videoFileName, outputExtension];

    encoder.outputFileType = stringOutputFileType;
    encoder.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
    encoder.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = optimizeForNetworkUse;
    encoder.videoSettings = @
    {
    AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
    AVVideoWidthKey: @1280,
    AVVideoHeightKey: @720,
    AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: @
        {
        AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: @1200000,
        AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264High40,
        },
    };
    encoder.audioSettings = @
    {
    AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @2,
    AVSampleRateKey: @44100,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey: @128000,
    };

    [encoder exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
     {
         if (encoder.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted)
         {
             if (saveToPhotoAlbum) {
                 UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoPath, self, nil, nil);
             }
             NSLog(@"Export Complete %d %@", encoder.status, encoder.error);
             [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:videoPath] callbackId:command.callbackId];
         }
         else if (encoder.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled)
         {
             NSLog(@"Video export cancelled");
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Export failed: %@", [[encoder error] localizedDescription]);
             [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:[[encoder error] localizedDescription]] callbackId:command.callbackId];
         }
         /*switch ([encoder status]) {
          case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:

          break;
          case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:

          break;
          case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
          NSLog(@"Export canceled");
          break;
          default:
          NSLog(@"Export default in switch");
          break;
          }*/

     }];
    /*if ([compatiblePresets containsObject:AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality])
     {
     AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]initWithAsset:avAsset presetName: presetName];
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *videoPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0], videoFileName, outputExtension];

     exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
     exportSession.outputFileType = stringOutputFileType;
     exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = optimizeForNetworkUse;

     NSLog(@"videopath of your file: %@", videoPath);

     if (videoDuration)
     {
     int32_t preferredTimeScale = 600;
     CMTime startTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, preferredTimeScale);
     CMTime stopTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(videoDuration, preferredTimeScale);
     CMTimeRange exportTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startTime, stopTime);
     exportSession.timeRange = exportTimeRange;
     }

     [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
     switch ([exportSession status]) {
     case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
     if (saveToPhotoAlbum) {
     UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoPath, self, nil, nil);
     }
     NSLog(@"Export Complete %d %@", exportSession.status, exportSession.error);
     [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:videoPath] callbackId:command.callbackId];
     break;
     case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
     NSLog(@"Export failed: %@", [[exportSession error] localizedDescription]);
     [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:[CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:[[exportSession error] localizedDescription]] callbackId:command.callbackId];
     break;
     case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
     NSLog(@"Export canceled");
     break;
     default:
     NSLog(@"Export default in switch");
     break;
     }
     }];
     }*/

}
```